# unique pairs storing in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck at a scenerio where i need to save user input like... (in 1 go i get these reuslt)

```
$string = "'a':'php,'b':'.Net' ...
'c'    'java'
'c'    'php'
'c'    'java'
'a'   'php'
'a'    'java' ";
```

Now i need to store all these values in a database (only unique pairs).

WHat i tried so far, exploded $string with "," and stored everything in an array like

$array["a"] = "php";...but this will overwrite a = java too... //problem

I don't need to check in database that if they exist already or not..this is handled already (all dumped data in one go get a unique identifier).

All i need to do is to get unique pairs and dump into database...means

```
a = php, a = java, b = .net, c = java, c=php
```

Only solution i could see was...after exploding ...check for the pair in db against new unique identified...mysql_num_rows...if does not exist then dump else dont...

Is there any easy way...??

Answer (score 0):

The best way for your purpose is to create the multidimensional array

```
            <?php

        $string = "'a':'php','b':'.Net','c':'java','c':'php','c':'java','a':'php','a':'java'";
        $array = array();

        $temp_arr = explode(",", $string);

        foreach($temp_arr as $key=>$value)
        {
            list($tempkey,$tempValue) = explode(':', $value);
            $tempKey    = trim($tempkey,"'");
            $tempValue  = trim($tempValue,"'");
            $array[$tempKey][] = $tempValue; 
        }


        $array = array_map('array_unique',$array);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);

        ?>
```

output will be

```
Array
(
[a] => Array
    (
        [0] => php
        [2] => java
    )

[b] => Array
    (
        [0] => .Net
    )

[c] => Array
    (
        [0] => java
        [1] => php
    )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = "'a':'php,'b':'.Net','c':'java','c':'php','c':'java','a':'php','a':'java'";

$temp = array_map(function($item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $item);
    return array(str_replace("'", "", $key) => str_replace("'", "", $value));
}, explode(",", $string));

$results = array();

foreach($temp as $item) {
    $key = key($item);
    if(!isset($results[$key]) || !in_array($item[$key], $results[$key])) {
        $results[$key][] = $item[$key];
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
    (
        [0] => php
        [1] => java
    )

    [b] => Array
    (
        [0] => .Net
    )

    [c] => Array
    (
        [0] => java
        [1] => php
    )

 )
```